# Bash script can't execute Go command

Tags: bash, go

I'm trying to write a bash script to automatically run a go get/install in different directories. The relevant part is here:

```
( cd ../web ; go get )
( cd ../web ; go install )
( cd ../services ; go get )
( cd ../services ; go install )
```

When I execute the script, I get this though:

- cd ../web
- go get
  ./staging.sh: line 43: go: command not found
- cd ../web
- go install
  ./staging.sh: line 44: go: command not found
- cd ../services
- go get
  ./staging.sh: line 45: go: command not found
- cd ../services
- go install
  ./staging.sh: line 46: go: command not found

If I just go to the directories manually and run the commands, they work fine. Why aren't they executing when running from the script?

Comment: Is `go` in the $PATH ?

Comment: Sounds like a path issue.. Try adding a `printenv | grep PATH` to your script and making sure the `go` binary is in one of the folders listed. If you just installed go, try starting a new terminal

Comment: I get the path as: `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`
Which is different than if I run grep the path when I go to the file. So it probably is a path issue. How can I make the script get the correct path?

Comment: Does `echo $SHELL` produce the same result when you run it in your interactive shell and your script? It might be that you are loading a different shell and that's not loading the .*rc file where your $PATH is getting properly set.

Comment: Yes, both print bin/bash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you followed the installation instructions on the go installation page that tell you to add some lines to your `~/.profile` file. This file [doesn't load for non-interactive sessions (eg; your script.)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247738/why-is-etc-profile-not-invoked-for-non-login-shells) So you either need to add it to your shell's rcfile, or reference the go binary by it's full path in your script.

You can find out the full path of `go` by running in your shell:

```
$ which go
/path/to/go
```

Then, in your script:

```
GO=/path/to/go
$GO command
```

Or, you can extend your `PATH` inside the script:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to
```

Comment: I've tried both of these. It recognizes the command now, but it won't download any of the third party libraries because GOPATH isn't set. I tried setting GOPATH in the script the same way it's set in the `~/.profile` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try doing the printenv again but this time without the grep.

Comment: Finally figured it out. After putting the paths in etc/bash.bashrc, it wasn't sourcing from there until I added:    
    `#!/bin/bash
    chmod a+x /etc/bash.bashrc
    PS1='$ '
    source /etc/bash.bashrc`